# Having trouble placing object files in a new directory using makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I am very new at make. Thus far I've managed to create the following using some of GNU manual and tutorials found online. I'd like for make to place all of the created object files into the directory 'obj.' I've been able to successfully create this directory, but I cannot figure out how to place the files in it. Any suggestions or tips are appreciated. Also, on a general note, is there a good source for learning how to work with make besides the GNU documentation?

```
# specify compiler
CC          := gcc
# set compiler flags
CFLAGS      := -M -Igen/display -Igen/logic -Iman -Ilib/include -pipe -march=native -ftime-report
# set linker flags
LDFLAGS     := -lglut32 -loglx -lopengl32 -Llib
# specify separate directory for objects
OBJDIR      := obj
# include all sources
SOURCES     := $(wildcard gen/display/*.c gen/logic/*.c man/*.c)
# create objects from the source files
OBJECTS     := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES)) 
# specify the name and the output directory of executable
EXECUTABLE  := win32/demo

# all isn't a real file
all: $(EXECUTABLE)

# compile
%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@   

# link
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

# clean objects
clean:
    @$(RM) -rf $(OBJDIR)

.PHONY: all clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you see a rule where the output generated does not go to the file `$@`, you know it's not right.  Make will set the `$@` automatic variable to the file name that it expects to be created and if the recipe does something different, the makefile will not work.

Your rule sends the file to `$(OBJDIR)/$@`, not `$@`, so it's not right.

So, you need to write your pattern rule like this:

```
%.o: %.c
        @mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

If that doesn't work you'll need to provide more information such as an example of the compile line make invokes, what errors you see, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been able to successfully create this directory, but I cannot
>   figure out how to place the files in it.

There are two parts writing to doing that explicitly.

- First, and most fundamental, is that **if you want `make` to create a file, you have to give it a rule for doing so**.  You do have a pattern rule that could, in principle, have that effect ...

  > ```
  > %.o: %.c
  >   # ...
  > ```

  ... but in practice, that rule cannot ever be matched to files in the `obj/` directory because your sources are not in that directory.  This might be more effective:

  ```
  $(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
      @mkdir -p $(@D)
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
  ```

  Note in particular how now the target of the rule matches the artifact actually produced by that rule.
- Second, **you must have a requirement to build the target of the rule**, usually by having it be a dependency of some other rule.  Observe that your variable defining the object files contributing to `$(EXECUTABLE)` *does not* rely on objects from the `obj/` directory.  It is generated by this pattern substitution ...

  > ```
  > OBJECTS     := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))
  > ```

  ... which generates object names with the same path as the corresponding sources.  You probably want something more like this:

  ```
  OBJECTS     := $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))
  ```

  You will note how that also corresponds to the change presented in the previous point.

But that's a lot of work for little gain.  You would not have to modify your `clean` target very much to do without it there.  You could write your file in a somewhat simpler and more conventional form and still get output into a separate directory by leveraging [the VPATH feature of GNU (and some other) `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Directory-Search.html#index-vpath).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is still not working. I get the following error: "*** No rule to make target." I modified my code per your suggestions.